# SQL: how to pull characters before the first space

Tags: sql, netezza

How do I pull characters before the first space, for fields that are not `NULL`?

For example:

```
Banana Bread
NULL
Chocolate Chip Cookie
```

Results:

```
Banana
NULL
Chocolate
```

Thanks!

Comment: That will depend on the RDBMS (SQL flavor) you are using.

Comment: Your question is not much clear to me and also is all these words stored in one column or each of them has it own column.

Comment: INSTR and SUBSTR

Comment: I don't use netezza, so I'm not 100% confident on this one, but I believe `SELECT get_value_varchar(array_split(yourfield, ' '), 1) FROM yourtable;` will get you in the ballpark. Documentation for [`get_value_varchar`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_get_value_type.html) and [`array_split`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_array_split.html). This will split the column delimited by space into an array, then retrieve the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the [documentation of the netezza string functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_char_funcs.html), I believe that you should be able to achieve this by using functions `instr()` and `substr()`, like :

```
substr(
    my_column, 
    1,
    instr(my_column, ' ') - 1
)
```

Basically, `instr(my_column, ' ')` gives you the position of the first space in the string ; substract `1` from it and you get the number of characters that you want to capture at the beginning of the string.

If given a `NULL` value, this expression should return `NULL` as well.

Answer (score 0):

on MS SQL Server:

```
select 
 Snack
,charindex(' ', Snack) SpaceLocation
,substring(Snack, 1, charindex(' ', Snack)-1) SubString
from (
    values
     ('Banana Bread')
    ,(NULL)
    ,('Chocolate Chip Cookie')
) t(Snack)
```

Answer (score 0):

select substring(FieldName, 1, charindex(' ',FieldName)) 
where FieldName IS NOT NULL